# Pod with restart policy never in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 containers in a pod. Main container and side car for sending logs to ELK.

I don't want the main container to restart when it fails, but I need the side car to get restarted automatically when it fails.

Setting RestartPolicy to Never is not restarting the side car also. Is there any way to set the restart policy at the container level?

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to accomplish with only restarting the side car but not the app container?  There currently is not any way to accomplish this that I know of.  I woiuld recommend looking into adding a custom probe to your podSpec https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes this may help with collecting the information you need.

Comment: Logging container is failing due to some issue. My main container is for a batch job and it is not support to start again if it failed for some reason.

Comment: How about running a kubernetes Job https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/

Answer (score 1):

We have a proposal to formalize sidecar container lifecycles: https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-apps/sidecarcontainers.md

Take a look at that and see if it gets to what you need?